# How to internationalize my Rails app using multiple languages tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, internationalization, globalize

I have a table (services) in DB with different columns for different languages (name_en, name_fr)  How to internationalize my Rails app using multiple languages tables in DB with out using gem globalize.

Comment: check these questions and read through their answers you will find how:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508033/how-to-internationalize-content-on-ruby-on-rails
https://github.com/globalize/globalize
https://www.synbioz.com/blog/tech/internationalization-with-globalize
https://lokalise.com/blog/store-translations-inside-database-globalize/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have set default_language(such as 'en' and 'fr') and having key(by which you will find translation value) column in your database.

You have to implement a **service class**

```
class Translation
  def self.get_translation(key = "")
    column_name = "name_#{default_language}"
    translated_value = Service.find_by_key(key)
    return key.humanize if translated_value.blank?
    eval("translated_value.#{column_name}") rescue key.humanize
  end
end
```

**Now you can use**

```
Translation.get_translation("")
```